# AWS amplify graphql mutation: Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am fairly new to both GraphQL and AWS amplify so this might be a newbie question.

I have defined the type listed below in schema.graphql. If I create a mutation using a type with `id: ID!`, I get a `Cannot return null for non-nullable field Vocabulary.id`.

How do I specify a field should be an `identity` field in AWS amplify graphql? specifying `id: ID!` for an `identity` field, in this [AWS amplify workshop](https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/40_graphql/10_setting_up_appsync.html) seems to work fine.

**~\amplify\backend\api\vidaudtranscription\schema.graphql**:

```
type Vocabulary @model 
@key(fields:["userId"])
@auth(rules: [{allow: owner}])
{
    id: ID!
  userId: String!
  vocabularies: [String!]!
}
```

**Mutation Request:**

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createVocabulary(input: {userId: "abc", vocabularies: ["123", "456"]}) {
    id
    owner
    userId
    vocabularies
  }
}
```

**Mutation Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "createVocabulary": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Vocabulary.id.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createVocabulary",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide `id` in your `input` argument:

```
createVocabulary(input: {userId: "abc", vocabularies: ["123", "456"]})
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The error is a bit hard to read but it contains all the information you need to decipher it:

- `"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Vocabulary.id."` is complaining that `Vocabulary.id` (in the Vocabulary object you're creating) can't be null, but it is
- `"path": ["createVocabulary", "id"]` is the location of the missing field, i.e. the "id" field in the `createVocabulary` structure

(I'm glossing over some of the details here. To be technically correct the error is from the *resolver* failing to serialize the response object, rather than interpret the input object. But if you provide the required fields in your input object the rest should work.)